# How a tail a file that is given as the output of a find function?

Tags: shell, tail

I'm brand new in Unix environment.
I would like to monitor the output of a calculation on a cluster with a function.
I have tried this function I have put inside my .bashrc file under the alias section:

```
function tj(){ 
    tail -100f $(find . -type f -name "*.o$1")
}
```

and then

```
tj 1234
```

to see what is in file `dm.o1234` but I'm not getting anything I want, actually nothing (only >).

Have you any ideas where the mistake(s) is (are)?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what actually happens? To me it looks like this should work. In fact, I just created a file `dm.o1234` with some random content, then I copied&pasted your function and called `tj 1234`. Works fine for me. The file `dm.o1234` is tailed as expected.

Comment: ah... :) I only have a > on my side.

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that I've put this function in under the alias area of my .bashrc file?

Comment: because indeed, if I copy/paste the function in the terminal, it works fine...

Comment: I'm not sure how you put the alias in your `.bashrc` file, so I can't say. If you simply define the function within `.bashrc` like above and the file is properly sourced, it should not make a difference (I just tried it - works for me). There are quite a few problems with your function as explained in Stéphane's excellent answer and you should certainly fix them. Nevertheless, if using bash and if the `find` command finds exactly one matching file that does not contain spaces or similar characters, it should do what you expected. So yeah, it's hard to pinpoint the exact source of your problem.

Comment: Do you **also** have an alias defined for `tj`?

Comment: Here is my .bashrc file:
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
 . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
alias la='ls -la'
function tj(){ tail -100f $(find * -type f -name "*.o$1");}

Comment: What's the output of `type -a tj`?

Comment: Sorry, not easy to read, basically, juste the aforementioned function under the #User specific aliases section

Comment: tj is aliased to `function _tj(){ tail -100f $(find * -type f -name "*.o865181")};_tj'
tj is a function
tj ()
{
    tail -100f $(find * -type f -name "*.o$1")
}

Comment: interesting to see a 865181 instead of the $1 ?

Comment: ok, I have renamed the function tj as tdj and now it works

Comment: I guess I have performed lots of operations without even understanding what they were supposed to do...

Comment: Please add that information (the output of `type` and the bashrc) to your question in a code section (see the formatting help) so we can see more easily and give more specific answers.

Comment: I was initially wanting to perform this operation with an alias so I performed several tries with alias tj. That was the problem, since after an unalias tj (I didn't knwo that old created alias were "kept in memory", everything is fixed.

Comment: We're happy to help. But don't forget to fix your function as detailed in Stéphane's answer. Otherwise you will likely run into problems in the future. :)

Answer (score 5):

It don't know what is the exact source of your problem, but your code is in *unspecified* territory here.

- `function tj()` is not standard function definition syntax, it's neither Bourne/POSIX syntax (which uses `tj()`) not Korn syntax (which uses `function tj` without `()`). Some shells (bash, zsh, pdksh) do support it mostly by accident.
- `tail -100f` is unspecified by POSIX. The POSIX syntax is `tail -f -n 100`
- POSIX `tail` takes at most one argument, the behaviour is unspecified if you pass more than one argument. Some implementations like GNU `tail` are able to watch more than one file in parallel, but many others don't. You could try installing tail-like commands designed for that like `multitail`
- `$(find...)` invokes the split+glob operator, so with the default value of `$IFS`, that would not work properly if any of the file paths contain space, tab, newline or wildcard characters. If `find` returns no file, it would also end-up `tail`ing stdin.

Here you could use `zsh` and define the command as

```
tj() multitail ./**/*.o$1(.)
```

It would report an error if there was no matching file (as opposed to `tail`ing stdin). Also note that contrary to `find`, it gives you a sorted list of files and skips hidden files or files in hidden directories (add the `D` glob qualifier if you want them).

---

Now, if, as per your edit, you see `>` when you run `tj`, when `>` is the default secondary prompt (`$PS2`), it looks more likely that  you have an alias also defined for `tj` (that alias probably defined *after* the definition of the `tj` function or otherwise that would have caused an error in the definition of the `tj` function).

For instance, it's the kind of thing you'd see if you had run:

```
alias tj='for sure'
```

(an unterminated `for` loop), or any code that is not self contained and for which the shell would issue a secondary prompt for you to finish it.

You can undefine that alias with `unalias tj` (and remove its definition from your `~/.bashrc` if it's there so it doesn't come back the next time you run `bash`).

Of course, there's also always the possibility that the only `*.o1234` file found contains just `>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Stéphane, now that is issue is fix, I will try to write the function in a more "documented" way

Comment: The OP use bash (using .bashrc), the answer is for zsh, excellent.